# Is there a way to decrypt the encrypted files (using ecryptFS) on Linux?

Tags: ecryptfs

I am using ecryptFS for encryption of data on Linux. Is there a way on Linux to decrypt the data without mounting the encrypted folder?

Comment: Using WSL and mounting the encrypted folder is probably more simple and more reliable than anything else...

Comment: Can we decrypt the encrypted files using passphrase ?

Comment: Could you explain why mounting is a problem? If you are worried about the integrity, make a copy and use that for decryption. Also: Windows-related questions are off-topic.

Comment: I have removed mention of Windows from your question since you asked about a way on "windows/Linux". A way on Windows is off topic for us, but a way on Linux would not be. If you require this to be on Windows, then please delete this questoin and ask again on [su].